# when uitableview calls reloaddata

Tags: ios, uitableview, datasource

Can someone clarify something for me.  Apple documentation for `UITableView` says

```
`UITableView` overrides the layoutSubviews method of `UIView` so that it calls reloadData only when you  create a new instance of `UITableView` or when you assign a new data source.
```

I'm getting the following behaviour:

In my `viewDidLoad`, I have `tableView.dataSource = self.`

In my `getDataFromDatabase`, I call `[tableView reloadData]`.  This seems to work fine, but I think what's happening is the table is being populated with a blank array, then, when the db call comes back, it's reloading it with an array with data.

I'm trying to do the following:
In `viewDidLoad`, remove `tableView.dataSource = self;`, and add it in the `getDataFromDatabase` method.  e.g.

```
(void)getDataFromDatabase
{
    [getData completionHandler^() // an async db call
    {
        tableView.dataSource = self;
    }];
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working.  The table is not populated.  It works if I add `[tableView reloadData]` after setting the `dataSource = self`, but from the documentation, shouldn't it call `reloadData` automatically when I set the `dataSource = self` "it calls reloadData only when you create a new instance of `UITableView` or when you assign a new data source."  ?

Comment: Please check your array after fetching detail from database. If your query would fail to fetch records then which data would be reload in table view

Comment: @Jason The given code has a number of typos. Maybe there's just an issue due to this. Please copy and paste code which the compiler was able to parse without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is your "completionHandler" running on main thread? If not or you are not sure about that, try executing your code on main thread. Because according to apple documentation, the result of not updating the UI on main thread is uncertain. You can try this:

```
[getData completionHandler^() // an async db call
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        tableView.dataSource = self;
    });

}];
```

Comment: Hi liuyaodong - Thanks for this.  I tried this, but it still doesn't seem to work.  Any other thoughts?  Very strange...